# How to listen to `iron-select` event in the child of iron-pages?

Tags: polymer-1.0, iron-elements

Consider the following code from PSK:-

```
<iron-pages
  selected="[[page]]"
  attr-for-selected="name"
  fallback-selection="view404"
  role="main">
<my-view1 name="view1"></my-view1>
<my-view2 name="view2"></my-view2>
<my-view3 name="view3"></my-view3>
<my-view404 name="view404"></my-view404>
</iron-pages>
```

Is it possible to listen to `iron-select` event within `<my-view#>` element whenever it is selected by `<iron-pages>`?

Comment: I don't think that will be possible. You could however call a function on your `<my-view#>` element when the `iron-select` event is fired.

Comment: Thanks for your pointer. I eventually use `_pageChaged` observer for my use case.